# get unobtrusive validation attributes by ViewModel Type

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I need something like

```
var dict = html.GetUnobtrusiveValidationAttributes<ViewModel1>(propName);
```

and I got it working like this:

```
public static IHtmlString GetVld<TModel>(this HtmlHelper html)
{
    ...

    foreach (var prop in typeof(TModel).GetProperties())
    {
        var attributes = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    
        Func<string, ModelMetadata, IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule>> ClientValidationRuleFactory 
            = (name, metadata) => ModelValidatorProviders.Providers.GetValidators(metadata ?? ModelMetadata.FromStringExpression(name, html.ViewData), html.ViewContext).SelectMany(v => v.GetClientValidationRules());

        var clientRules = ClientValidationRuleFactory(prop.Name, null);
        UnobtrusiveValidationAttributesGenerator.GetValidationAttributes(clientRules, attributes);
```

**the only problem is** that I have to call this in a view with `@model` in order for it to work, otherwise `attributes` will always be empty

```
@model MyVM // I want to make it work without this line
@Html.GetVld<MyVM>()
```

I tried doing:
`var html2 = new HtmlHelper<TModel>(html.ViewContext, html.ViewDataContainer)` and using `html2` instead of `html` but it won't help.